# How to align the button right next to the search box

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align the search button right next to the search box however button seems to be below. This is what I got:

```
        <form action="{linkto page="search.php"}" method="get" id="searchFormTest">
           <input type="text" id="searchPhrase" name="searchPhrase" class="searchInputBox" value="{$lang.enterKeywords}" placeholder="Suchbegriff oder Bildnummer">
              <div style="display: inline;">
                <button type="submit" value="Submit">
                  <i style="font-size: 40px;" class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
               </button>
              </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Post more markup please. Is your search input set to `display: block;` ? Try floating your search box.

Comment: Looks like it's next to it already? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpyKpX

Comment: Display : inline-block or display:flex will work for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <div style="display: inline;">
  <input type="text"/>
         <span>   <button type="submit" value="Submit">
                <i style="font-size: 20px;" class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
            </button>
        </div>
```

this should work to have the icon right next to the search box.

Answer (score 4):

Float your search input to the left, float your submit button to the left. Ready.

```
input[type="search"],
button {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You code works just fine in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ygvucw5c/). I think you should look into css styles which are being inherited by the button.

```
<form method="get" id="searchFormTest">
    <input type="text" id="searchPhrase" name="searchPhrase" class="searchInputBox" placeholder="Suchbegriff oder Bildnummer">
    <div style="display: inline;">
        <button type="submit" value="Submit">
            <i style="font-size: 15px;" class="fa fa-search" aria-hidden="true">Search</i>
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```